# Case that is philosophically right or wrong, but semantically wrong

Tags: grammaticality, comparison, semantics

If we see that there is a red apple, but someone says 'we see that there is a red apple, but it's green.' Then, is it semantically wrong?

Comment: It is possible to formulate statements which are 'grammatically' correct, but nonsensical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it grammatically wrong?

No. You have to distinguish between syntax (grammar) and semantics (meaning).

A lie can be grammatical and the truth can be ungrammatical.

> Syntax and Semantics are two very important branches in linguistics.
> Linguistics is the study of language. Syntax is the study of the
> structure of sentence while semantics is the study of meaning in
> language. Therefore, the main difference between syntax and semantics
> is that syntax is concerned with structure while semantics is
> concerned with meaning.
>
> https://pediaa.com/difference-between-syntax-and-semantics/

Answer (score 0):

Grammar and philosophy are two very different things. This isn't a site for philosophy, but let's correct your grammar and then talk about what it might mean.

> We see there being a red apple, but it's green.

This is grammatically incorrect. I think you're trying to say:

> We *see* that the apple is red, but *actually*, it is green.

This would mean that we *perceive* the colour red, but for some reason our perception is incorrect. What that means philosophically, I don't know. I would want more context - does the speaker mean that something was deliberately has interfered with our perception, or is this just about language conditioning? If is often posited that if we were told that the colour everybody perceives as 'red' is actually called green, we would call it that.

If a statement is true or untrue, fact or fiction, simple or abstract, it still needs to be grammatically correct to be properly understood.